# My SQL Workbench Cannot insert an auto-generated id into table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, primary-key, mysql-error-1064

```
`INSERT INTO terms (terms_id, terms_description, terms_due_days)
VALUES (AUTO_INCREMENT, 'Special terms', 90)`
```

I am trying to insert an auto generated id a term description and an int into an  SQL table .
Run the query i get the error

```
"00:01:57   INSERT INTO terms (terms_id, terms_description, terms_due_days) VALUES (AUTO_INCREMENT, 'Special terms', 90)    Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'AUTO_INCREMENT' in 'field list'   0.000 sec
```

So my question is how do I add a record of the next auto incremented number in the id array

Here is a snapshot of the db

[image: databaseCol]

Comment: Please review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expected usage of an auto increment column is to simply omit it from the insert, which will tell MySQL to auto generate the value:

```
INSERT INTO terms (terms_description, terms_due_days)
VALUES ('Special terms', 90);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create table using this query first.

**CREATE TABLE terms (
    terms_id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    terms_description VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   terms_due_days int(5) NOT NULL
    );**

Then Try insert

**INSERT INTO terms (terms_id, terms_description, terms_due_days) VALUES ( 'Special 
    terms', 90)**